# How to set a Property unique in EF6 code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have this class:

```
public class BSC
{
    public int BSCId { get; set; }

    public string BSCName { get; set; }
}
```

and the config class:

```
public class BSCConfig :EntityTypeConfiguration<BSC>
{
    public BSCConfig()
    {
        Property(m => m.BSCName).HasMaxLength(50).HasColumnName("Category").IsRequired();

    }
}
```

I want to make this property Unique, but I do not have isUnique or Index method.

Can you please tell me how to make this property Unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `HasColumnAnnotation` :

```
Property(m => m.BSCName).HasMaxLength(50).HasColumnName("Category").IsRequired()
  .HasColumnAnnotation("Index",
   new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_X_Category") { IsUnique = true }));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with data annotations.

```
[Index("IX_X_Category", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public string BSCName { get; set; }
```